# How to loop through files whose names contain vertical lines and spaces in bash

Tags: bash, files

This classical solution (when there are only spaces in the names) didn't work

```
find . -name '*.html' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d ''; do
```

because the html files additionally contain vertical lines (`|`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find . -name '*.html' -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d ''; do
```

There is nothing on that line that would have any sort of problems with filenames containing combinations of spaces and/or pipes in their names:

```
bash-4.4$ touch 'A|B' '1|2' 'quux|foo bar'
bash-4.4$ ls
1|2          A|B          quux|foo bar
bash-4.4$ find . -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d ''; do printf '"%s"\n' "$REPLY"; done
"."
"./A|B"
"./1|2"
"./quux|foo bar"
```

Notice too that depending on what you'd like to do with the found names, it almost always better to do that with an `-exec` from within `find` itself:

```
find . -type f -name "A*" -exec cat {} \;
```

Related answer to another question: [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/116858) (see especially "How do I process files found by find?" in that answer).

Comment: Sorry it was a lack of attention from my part. Thanks for exec advice anyway

Answer (score 0):

You only need such a simple invocation of `find` for very old versions of `bash` (pre-4.0). Using the `globstar` operator is much simpler:

```
shopt -s globstar
for f in **/*.html; do
    ...
done
```